# Masking Character to Asterisk in kotlin using PasswordTransformationMethod

Tags: android, kotlin

How to change default masking character to asterik in textinputedittext for password field in kotlin android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom `PasswordTransformationMethod` and provide asterisk char

```
class AsteriskTransformationMethod : PasswordTransformationMethod() {
    
    override fun getTransformation(source: CharSequence, view: View): CharSequence {
        return object : CharSequence {
            override val length: Int
                get() = source.length

            override fun get(index: Int) = '*'

            override fun subSequence(startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int): CharSequence {
                return source.subSequence(startIndex, endIndex)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then set it to `TextInputEditText` programatically

```
 textInputEditText.transformationMethod = AsteriskTransformationMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom method which can mask based on your need:

```
fun String.mask(
        maskString: String = "*",
        maskAfterLetters: Int = 3,
        isFixSize: Boolean = true,
        maxSize: Int = 10,
        selector: String = "."
): String {
    if(maskAfterLetters < 0) throw RuntimeException("Invalid masking configuration - maskAfterLetters should be greater than 0")
    if(isFixSize && maxSize <= maskAfterLetters) throw RuntimeException("Invalid masking configuration - maxSize must be greater than maskAfterLetters")
    val text = if(isFixSize && length >= maxSize) substring(0, maxSize) else this
    val unmaskLength = if(maskAfterLetters <= length) maskAfterLetters else length
    return text.substring(0, unmaskLength) + text.substring(unmaskLength, text.length).replace(selector.toRegex(), maskString)
}
```

here created an extension function on string to mask with some default value which mask the given string to `*`.

Below are the arguments and their usage:

- `maskString`: String or char which will be coming at the place of actual string
- `maskAfterLetters`: Specify the number of letters which will be preserved in masked output
- `isFixSize`: Specify if the output masked string will be of fixed size or not
- `maxSize`: If returned masked string of fixed size, then it specify what will be size of masked output
- `selector`: Selector pattern to replace with masked string (no need to change normally)

There are may other APIs for masking (Jakson ObjectMapper with masking) but this is the simplest solution.